# checkbox selected in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox

Hi i have this select checkbox which is weekdays the checkboxes were `sunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday`. Users can able to choose as many as they want. And i save the data to my database,like for example users choose sunday monday tuesday, i save that into my fields as 1-2-3 with only one field name available_days_per_week. Now my problem is when i queried the data and display into my edit page i want that only 1-2-3 will be checked. What happened is the data doubles. My code works but displays into double. Heres my code below

```
 <tr>
                            <th>Available days per week</th>
                            <td>
                            <?php $daysPerWeeks = $query->available_days_per_week; ?>
                            <?php $daysPerWeeks1 = explode("-", $daysPerWeeks); ?>
                            <?php foreach($daysPerWeeks1 as $value): ?>
                              <?php foreach($daysPerWeekCheckboxes as $key=>$week): ?>
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php echo($value == $key) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> ><?php echo $week; ?><br>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>      
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

that will display into my page like this

```
<tr>
                            <th>Available days per week</th>
                            <td>
                                                                                                                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="1" checked="checked" >Sunday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="2"  >Monday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="3"  >Tuesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="4"  >Wendesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="5"  >Thursday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="6"  >Friday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="7"  >Saturday<br>
                                                                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="1"  >Sunday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="2" checked="checked" >Monday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="3"  >Tuesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="4"  >Wendesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="5"  >Thursday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="6"  >Friday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="7"  >Saturday<br>
                                                                                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="1"  >Sunday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="2"  >Monday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="3" checked="checked" >Tuesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="4"  >Wendesday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="5"  >Thursday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="6"  >Friday<br>
                                                                  <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="7"  >Saturday<br>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

as youve noticed it wil double 
heres my static code that will return days of weeks

```
//return days per week checkbox
  public static function getDaysPerWeekCheckbox(){
    return array(
      1 =>'Sunday',
      2 =>'Monday',
      3 =>'Tuesday',
      4 =>'Wendesday',
      5 =>'Thursday',
      6 =>'Friday',
      7 =>'Saturday'
    );

  }
```

How can i avoid the data that will not doubled when displaying in the edit page?.
Can someone help me figured this thing out?.Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping unnecessarily. Try this:

```
<?php $days = getDaysPerWeekCheckbox(); ?>
<?php foreach($days as $index => $day_name): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="<?php echo $index ?>" <?php echo(in_array($index, $daysPerWeeks1)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> ><?php echo $day_name; ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: got error in this line of code in yours
 <input type="checkbox" name="available_days_week" value="<?php echo $index ?>" <?php echo(in_array($index, $daysPerWeeks1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''?> ><?php echo $day_name; ?><br>

Comment: got this error
 Function name must be a string
this line of code
 <?php $days = $daysPerWeekCheckboxes(); ?>

Comment: hey thanks ive fixed it! i remove this line of code
<?php $days = $daysPerWeekCheckboxes(); ?>